# Question on Spring 3 autoscan and required annotation

Tags: java, spring

I have a class annotated with spring `Component` e.g:

```
@Component
public class ImportantClass{

@Autowired
private DependentClassIF otherClass;

//getters setters

@Required 
public void setOtherClass(DependentClassIF c){
this.otherClass = c;    
}
```

---

```
public interface DependentClassIF {
    //methods here
}  
 @Component
 public class DependentClass implements DependentClassIF {
    //implementation here
 }
```

I use autoscan to detect beans instead of declaring them all in the bean conf file.
I get

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException:
>   Property 'otherClass' is required for
>   bean 'ImportantClass'

My question is the following:
In autoscan, doesn't Spring make sure that all the **required** properties are injected?
If I remove the `@Required` it works, but I am not sure I understand Spring's behavior on this.

Any input is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Autowired` has `required` set to true, so you don't need `@Required`

You don't need `@Requried` with annotation-based injection. It is meant to be used with xml configuration, to denote that a property must be set in the xml.

Comment: You mean 2 annotations at the same place?If I do `@Autowired @Required` over `private DependentClassIF otherClass;` I get error: `the annotation @Required is disallowed for this location`